# How to get Next Week Monday Date and Next Week Sunday Date using SSRS Expresion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I Need to get next week monday and sunday date using SSRS expression. please help me out from this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The reporting service uses a SQL Query (command text).  So see : https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=185092

Comment: I need to get using Ssrs expressions. Not from sql query

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide examples based on actual dates, what happens if you execute the code on a Sunday or Monday what dates are you expecting back? You need to provide more info. You also need to look back over some of your previous questions and mark answers as accepted. You have asked 6 questions, most answered, but none are marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code
**For Sunday next week**

```
=DATEADD("d" ,7-DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay,Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday),Today())
```

**For Monday next week**

```
=DATEADD("d" ,8-DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay,Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday),Today())
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will check with this.

Comment: Thank you Benzi. its working for me some other scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
=Format(Cdate(Split(First(Fields!Output1.Value, "OutputFilters"),"-")(1)).AddDays(8DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay,Cdate(Split(First(Fields!Output1.Value,"OutputFilters"),"-")(1)),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)),"MM/dd/yyyy")+"-"+Format(Cdate(Cdate(Split(First(Fields!Output1.Value, "OutputFilters"),"-")(1)).AddDays(8DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay,Cdate(Split(First(Fields!Output1.Value,"OutputFilters"),"-")(1)),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)).AddDays(6)),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dileep Kumar. This is what exactly i want. its working for me thank you.